# evaluating ( this.props.navigator ) Undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, navigator, react-native

I'm getting this error even though i'm passing in the navigator porp properly.

MySetup is in this way : Main navigator Page -> FirstView (onBtnPress) -> Details

I'm getting the error when i'm calling this.navigator.push in the firstView page.

**Main File:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Navigator
} from 'react-native';

class app extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
    }


   navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
        return <route.component navigator={navigator}/>

  }
     configureScene() {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalDownSwipeJump;
  }


    render() {

      return (
     <Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute= {{component: MainMapView}}
        renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}/>
      );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', padding: 20 }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => app);
```

**First Component:**

```
    <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(30,144,255,1)" style={styles.fabIcon}
                  onPress={this.fabPress}>
    </ActionButton>


  fabPress() {
  this.props.navigator.push({
      component : DetaislView
    });
  }
```

The error occurs on fabPress.

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this in your **FirstComponent.js**:

```
class FirstComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.fabPress = this.fabPress.bind(this);
    }

    // ... rest of the code remains the same
```

---

#### Why we had to do this?

Back in time when we were using `React.createClass` (ES5), class methods were automatically bound to the class. But when we started to `extend` (ES6 classes), we need to bind the methods explicitly to the class env.

`fabPress` being passed as an event's callback function, it is executed in another env outside the class; hence the `this` will be coming from the scope of execution env. But we need `this` of our class to access `this.props.navigator` :)

Comment: no Change. sam error. btw.. what does this code do?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if anyone is interested in why this doesn't work even if you are having the function inside the class.

The function isn't binded to the class if declared as shown in the following.

```
  theFunctionName() {
         // your code
  }
```

The function is binded to the class if it is declared with the following syntax.

```
  theFunctionName = () => {
         // your code
  }
```

thus you can omitt the `bind(this)` code.

reference taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034617/passing-props-state-in-react-native-navigator)

**Please make sure you have the necessary presets. Since the arrow function is highly experimental feature (as of this period in time)**

Comment: **Caveat:** Defining class methods as [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is a highly experimental feature. Make sure you've the necessary presets.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I passed in the navigator:

```
  onPress={this.fabPress(navigator)}

  fabPress(navigator) {
    navigator.push({component: DetaislView});
  }
```

Comment: what is  component: DetaislView?